# Expanding div to fit beside a float right div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out this layout issue, and I'm not entirely certain it's possible, but I thought someone here might have an idea.

```html
<div class="outer" style="width:500px;">

  <div class="rightFloat" style="float:right; width:max-content; height: 50px; background-color: transparent;">
    <P>
      This is content that should be right float.
    </P>
  </div>

  <div class="Content" style="background-color:#eeeeac;">

    <div class="conditionalDiv" style="background-color: #eeacee;  border: 2px solid black">
      This is conditional content that should not push the right float content down. The pink background should not be under the float content.
    </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor pharetra quam id ullamcorper. Donec venenatis felis eu pulvinar porta. In non facilisis leo. Nulla ut lorem at enim tincidunt viverra. Vivamus id tempus eros. Fusce ultrices lectus sed ante hendrerit, et auctor tortor consectetur. Nam egestas sem tempor urna convallis, non maximus libero condimentum. Nullam non egestas neque.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I would like to do is to have the conditionalDiv (pink, conditional content that may or may not be present) only take up the space leading up to the rightFloat div.  The rightFloat div should remain a consistent size (it's currently defined as width:max-content; I'd prefer not setting a fixed size if it can be avoided).  In the referenced code, a working solution would have the border and background of the conditionalDiv not overlapping the space under the rightFloat div. (Float background should be white, with no border.)

The goal is that if the conditionalDiv is present, it's displayed beside the rightFloat div, and the main content continues below.  Otherwise, if the conditional (pink) div is not present, the yellow content wraps around the rightFloat div.

I've tried a variety of ordering changes.  I did a short test with flexbox, but I'm not sure a flexbox would work well in the conditional div situation.

Is there something I'm missing that would give me the behaviour I'm looking for?

Comment: You properly want to look into Flexbox or CSS-Grid. You should use float only for its intended purpose (floating an element within a text-block like a newspaper image).

Comment: Just make the pink box `display:flow-root;`

Comment: @tacoshy Technically, that's what I want to do, albeit with the added wrinkle of a small bordered block of text occasionally appearing at the start of the content.  (the conditionalDiv).   I looked at CSS grid, but I'm not sure I could get an L shaped cell (conditionalDiv + content) using it.